# How do I get the input element to be selected? (text highlighted)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text, input

I need your help,

Currently, when I click the 'rename' button, all works well as it should, but i'd like to add functionality such that not only is the original text value of the LI inside the input box but to also automatically make the text (highlighted) resulting in the pic below:

[image]

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nc4pow56/1/

The code in question

```
$(function(){
    $('#colors li').click(fn);

    $('button').click(fn);

    function fn(e){
    var el = $('li.active');
    if(e.target.type != "button"){
            el.removeClass('active');
            $(e.target).addClass('active');
    }else{  
        var txt = el.text(); 
        var newEl = $("<input>");
        newEl.blur(function(){
            el.html(newEl.val());       
        });
        newEl.val(txt);
        el.html(newEl);  
        newEl.focus();
    }     
    }   
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this `newEl.focus().select()`

Full Code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#colors li').click(fn);

    $('button').click(fn);

    function fn(e){
    var el = $('li.active');
    if(e.target.type != "button"){
            el.removeClass('active');
            $(e.target).addClass('active');
    }else{  
        var txt = el.text(); 
        var newEl = $("<input>");
        newEl.blur(function(){
            el.html(newEl.val());       
        });
        newEl.val(txt);
        el.html(newEl);  
        newEl.focus().select();
    }     
    }   
})();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: My eyes didn't pick up on something so obvious. Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to take a quick once over. Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes my friend, that is the taste of programming :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `newEl.focus()` with `newEl[0].select();` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/nc4pow56/4/)).